# Insert a space before the first comma in a csv file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a huge CSV file which contains 100000 rows. However, I need to do some processing and so for that I need to have a single space before the first comma. My current data is something like below.

```
123456,5,4,3,2,1
```

I need a space before the first comma for some internal processing. So, after the command execution, I need the file to be like below.

```
123456 ,5,4,3,2,1
```

I tried the gawk command to get the first column alone using $1. However, $1 gives me the entire row. Is there another way to do the above task?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you really meant "space *before* the first comma", since Stephane changed it?

Comment: Yeah, I needed space before first comma. However, I got the idea from sed command. Thanks agaiN!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with sed using `sed 's/,/ ,/'`.

```
$ sed 's/,/ ,/' <<< 123456,5,4,3,2,1
123456 ,5,4,3,2,1
```

Without the "g" modifier, `sed` only acts on the first match on a line (with "g", it acts on all of them).

Comment: I am using the command as below. sed 's/,/ ,/' <<< file.csv >> file1.csv
But however, I get only file1.csv inside the file1.csv as the content. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AAh, figured out. I don't need the <<< in the input file specification. Thanks a lot!